# Integrate New Spring MVC framework for coming module and struts 1 and hibernate 2 based existing framework in single web application web.xml

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, web.xml, sessionfactory

Currently **I am working on struts 1,spring 2 and hibernate 2** based web application.now we are going to add some more module in our application but the requirement is that we have to **integrate new module with spring MVC framework without doing any changes for existing module**.

1. So how can i integrate new **spring MVC framework** and **existing framework** in single application together ?
2. What changes i have to do in **web.xml** file ?
3. So is it possible to use (**hibernate 2 and hibernate 4**) jars and (**spring 2  and spring 4**) jars in single application ?
4. If it is possible then **what about hibernate session factory** , how this is going to be handled ?

Answer (score 0):

Its quite bad idea I think.  Especially packing different versions into one jar may cause several compile and runtime problems. You shouldn't do it.

Two different MVC frameworks for one web application is probably not impossible but also very bad decision.

If you cannot drop existing code/project, you should start with clean new seperate project and try to configure them to run side by side on production. But no mix up.